# System call in Ruby

Tags: ruby, system

I'm a beginner in ruby and in programming as well and need help with system call for moving a file from source to destination like this:

```
system(mv "#{@SOURCE_DIR}/#{my_file} #{@DEST_DIR}/#{file}")
```

Is it possible to do this in Ruby?  If so, what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`system("mv #{@SOURCE_DIR}/#{my_file} #{@DEST_DIR}/#{file})`

can be replaced with

`system("mv", "#{@SOURCE_DIR}/#{my_file}", "#{@DEST_DIR}/#{file}")`

which reduces the chances of a command line injection attack.

Answer (score 9):

Two ways

**Recommended way**

You can use the functions in the File Utils libary see [here](http://stdlib.rubyonrails.org/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/index.html) to move your files e.g

```
mv(src, dest, options = {})


Options: force noop verbose

Moves file(s) src to dest. If file and dest exist on the different disk 
partition, the file is copied instead.

FileUtils.mv 'badname.rb', 'goodname.rb'
FileUtils.mv 'stuff.rb', '/notexist/lib/ruby', :force => true  # no error

FileUtils.mv %w(junk.txt dust.txt), '/home/aamine/.trash/'
FileUtils.mv Dir.glob('test*.rb'), 'test', :noop => true, :verbose => true
```

**Naughty way**

Use the backticks approach (run any string as a command)

```
result = `mv "#{@SOURCE_DIR}/#{my_file} #{@DEST_DIR}/#{file}"`
```

Ok, that's just a variation of calling the **system** command but looks much naughtier!

Comment: Ok, thank you for all the answers.
If I move and rename the file over NFS file system, what does really happen after File.rename? Does File.rename pull the file to my local file system and rename it and push(move) it back to destination or it does the rename operation on destination?

Comment: The remote NFS server is responsible for handling the rename. As far as all local programs are concerned, the file is local but it's the job of the NFS driver to make it appear as if it were local.

Files are never copied locally for rename or move operations.

Answer (score 3):

```
system("mv #{@SOURCE_DIR}/#{my_file} #{@DEST_DIR}/#{file})
```

should be the correct call

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [Tanaka akira's escape library](http://www.a-k-r.org/escape/)
Here is example from one my app:

```
cmd = Escape.shell_command(['python', Rails::Configuration.new.root_path + '/script/grab.py']).to_s
system cmd
```